# Desaturate effect is not letting me set custom colors

Tags: c#, xna, shader, effects

I know very little about how to create a shader so I did some research on how to do a desaturation effect and borrowed the shader code for it. A problem I have now is when I try to set a custom color it seems to ignore any values I give. I wanted to draw something completely black yet `Color.Black` as well as `new Color(0, 0, 0, screen.SATURATION)` did not work. In fact it looks the same no matter what RGB values I put in.

Here's the code for the shader:

```
sampler TextureSampler : register(s0);

float4 main(float4 color : COLOR0, float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    // Look up the texture color.
    float4 tex = tex2D(TextureSampler, texCoord);

    // Convert it to greyscale. The constants 0.3, 0.59, and 0.11 are because
    // the human eye is more sensitive to green light, and less to blue.
    float greyscale = dot(tex.rgb, float3(0.3, 0.59, 0.11));

    // The input color alpha controls saturation level.
    tex.rgb = lerp(greyscale, tex.rgb, color.a * 4);

    return tex;
}


technique Desaturate
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 main();
    }
}
```

My Begin is as such:

```
ScreenManager.SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, null, null, null, desaturateEffect, Resolution.getTransformationMatrix() * cam.get_transformation(graphics.GraphicsDevice));
```

Another side effect of  the shader is that when I fade things out via `color * float` it seems to desaturate it as well. That one I kind of understand because the third variable of color is a: alpha which is where I am placing the desaturate variable to do its effect. Perhaps someone could help me understand what's going on here and perhaps what I could do to regain the ability to modify color as well as keep my dynamic control over saturation.

Comment: I haven't got much to do with HLSL, but looking at your `main(...)` shader function makes me think: aren't using only `a` element of `color`, i.e. Alpha? I don't see you using `r`, `g` or `b` anywhere.

Comment: Because you are making a Linear Interpolation (`lerp` function, isn't it?) between your texture color and greyscale of it, of course it will become grey, not black or red or whatever you want. I'm not sure if it'll work, but try multiplating your `greyscale` by `color.rgb`. If `color` is white, i.e. `(1, 1, 1)`, then nothing should happen. If it's black, your grayscale should become `(0, 0, 0)`, so black. If it's e.g. red, your grayscale should be only in `r` element, so: '(grayscale, 0, 0)`, thus giving you "redscale", rather than grayscale.

Comment: Apparently if statements are supported so may be a way for me to add something like `if(color.a != 999)` as a condition for it to lerp the color. Some condition statement for me to exclude certain things from the effect and not have it mess with the RGB values I set something I'm drawing to.

Comment: I suppose the best way to do it would be to draw it in a separate area that the effect isn't applied to, I just want to draw it there for layer/positional reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify a color value in `SpriteBatch.Draw()`, it gets passed into the input parameter with the `COLOR0` semantic.  That is to say, here:

```
float4 main(float4 color : COLOR0, float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
```

The `float4 color` parameter will be given the value that you pass in through `SpriteBatch.Draw()` because it is marked as `COLOR0`.

A bog-standard pixel shader which does nothing except output a tinted texture color looks like this:

```
float4 main(float4 color : COLOR0, float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    return tex2D(TextureSampler, texCoord) * color;
}
```

Note the multiplication by `color`.  This multiplies the texture's R by the color's R, the texture's G by the color's G, and so on through B and A, tinting the original color provided by the texture.

So what you probably want to do is this:

```
float4 main(float4 color : COLOR0, float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    // Look up the texture color.
    float4 tex = tex2D(TextureSampler, texCoord);
    tex.rgb *= color.rgb;

    // Convert it to greyscale. The constants 0.3, 0.59, and 0.11 are because
    // the human eye is more sensitive to green light, and less to blue.
    float greyscale = dot(tex.rgb, float3(0.3, 0.59, 0.11));

    // The input color alpha controls saturation level.
    tex.rgb = lerp(greyscale, tex.rgb, color.a * 4);

    return tex;
}
```

This will tint the original texture color--but only the RGB channels--before calculating the greyscale value or doing the lerp.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of what it's doing. One problem I'm having now is that I cannot fade things out via `new Color(r, g, b, SATURATION) * 0.5f` for example to make it be halfway transparent. The only change was `tex.rgb *= color.rgb;` so I don't see why that affected being able to fade things out.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're not going to be able to decouple your alpha from your saturation using this shader.  You'd have to include the alpha component in the multiplication step: `tex *= color;` which would cause something to fade out the more saturated it is.  You could specify either the alpha or (preferably) the saturation factor in a shader parameter, but then every sprite in the batch would have to have the same value.

Comment: hmm I have the saturation level as a variable in my gameplay screen.  Could I just reference that variable from the effects file?

Comment: Problem being there's no constructor to pass in a reference to the gameplay screen since you just Content.Load the desautrate effect. I see why this effect passes in the saturation level via the alpha variable as it's one of the few ways to get a variable in there it seems!

Comment: You can set shader parameters at the same time that you call `SpriteBatch.Begin()`.  Just do `myShader.Parameters["Saturation"].SetValue(value);` and make sure that you declare `float Saturation;` at the top of the shader file.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help with with. I have `desaturateEffect.Parameters["Saturation"].SetValue(SATURATION);` and added the new variable to the shader and in the shader I changed it to `tex.rgb = lerp(greyscale, tex.rgb, Saturation * 4);` using the new Saturation variable that I'm sending in versus using `color.a`. This frees up the color.a to be used as the alpha again as I understand it though I can seem to figure out how to get the alpha working again with the new changes I've made. Otherwise doing saturation that way appears to be working great.

Comment: nvm I seem to have it now with `return tex * color.a;`. Thanks again for all of the help!